# NO photos in ios simulator 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios

Upgraded from ios 5.1 to 6.0. There are no photos in Simulator 6.o for ImagePicker. I created .../DCIM/100APPLE/..and put in photos there, but again don't show up in simulator 6.0 ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've noticed the same behavior with the iOS 6.0 simulator.  If you save photos within the simulator, the `Media/DCIM/100APPLE` directory gets created.  But subsequently adding new photographs manually via the filesystem does not add them to the Photos app in the simulator.

For now, it appears we are stuck with other ways of adding photos.  You can drag photos one-by-one to the simulator which opens the file URL in MobileSafari.  From there, a long press on the image will allow you to add the image to the library.

Comment: will try it . Thanks, good thing I still have 5.1 on, so I can use that at least for photos.